# Javascript: How to show time in milliseconds as days: hours: min?

Tags: javascript, average

I have seen few post in here about this issue but I couldn't find the one as my case. So I have a table with three columns say column A, B and C where A and B includes dates in the form of "3/9/2016 4:28:42 PM". Column C is the difference of columns A and B. I got the difference but in milliseconds. I need each records of the column in days: hours: min format. I have seen one post [Javascript show milliseconds as days:hours:mins without seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528382/javascript-show-milliseconds-as-dayshoursmins-without-seconds) but couldn't implement in my loop. Here is the JavaScript I am working on. How do I do it?

```
    ' SQL = some statements

    <script>
        $(function() {
            ShowDifference();
            ShowAverage();
        });
         function ShowDifference() {
            var assigned; 
            var completed;
            var difference;
            $('#tbl tr').each(function() {
            assigned = new Date($(this).find('.assigned').html())
            completed = new Date($(this).find('.completed').html())
            difference = completed - assigned;
               // $(this).find('.difference').html(difference/1000/60/60);
            $(this).find('.difference').html(difference);
            });
        }
        function ShowAverage() {
           var difference = Number(0);
           var countRows = Number(0);
           var average;
           $('#tbl tr .difference').each(function() {
               countRows = ($(this).html() !== '') ? countRows + 1 : countRows;
               difference += Number($(this).html());
           });
           average = Number(difference / countRows);
           $("#tbla #average").html(average);
           }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of your HTML structure?

Comment: Save yourself the headache and use this: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: which variable contain the milliseconds??

Comment: I have added my html code

Comment: @FrayneKonok: variable "difference"  contain milliseconds value

Comment: @VicStat, checkout my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to seconds (*by dividing by 1000*), then convert to hours (*by dividing by 3600*) and the remainder divide by 60 to get minutes.

All calculations are being done on the total seconds so in comments i describe what is being used for the calculation

```
function ShowDifference() {
    var assigned; 
    var completed;
    var difference;

    $('#tbl tr').each(function() {
        assigned = new Date($(this).find('.assigned').html())
        completed = new Date($(this).find('.completed').html())
        difference = completed - assigned;

        var totalSeconds = difference / 1000;
        var days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400); // 86400 = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds per day
        var hours = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 86400) / 3600); // 3600 = 60 minutes * 60 seconds per day
        var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60); // 60 = 60 seconds per minute

        // $(this).find('.difference').html(difference/1000/60/60);
        $(this).find('.difference').html(days + ":" + hours + ':' + minutes);
    });
}
```

Comment: added days as well, as i had not noticed you wanted that too

Comment: Added `Math.floor` to the results to remove decimals.

Comment: Thanks alot. However, I got  "NaN:NaN:NaN" for empty columns.

Comment: Also I wanted or thought to calculate average of those time difference calculated thinking it may be helpful to other people. I had added my code for calculating average and display it somewhere in another small table. However, It doesn't show the average. I think it is because the "difference" variable had changed. Can anyone tell me where did I do wrong?

Comment: for the empty cells, just add a check beforehand and if `find('.assigned').html()` or `find('.assigned').html()` are empty ignore the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just place `1439198499` with your `difference`.

Here is the jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr883o0u/1/)

I use console for the output.

**Try this:**

```
var date = new Date(1439198499*1000);

// Days part from the timestamp
var days = date.getDay();

// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();


// Will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
console.log(formattedTime);
```

**Output**

> 1:15:21