# How do I turn milliseconds into days, hours and minutes with jQuery?

Tags: duration, milliseconds

I have a duration in milliseconds that I want to turn into days, hours in minutes so the output looks like this:

> "473 days 17 hours and 28 minutes"

I can't find an answer to how to do this. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: nothing to do with jquery. that's just basic math...

Comment: [JavaScript: Convert milliseconds to object with days, hours, minutes, and seconds](https://gist.github.com/remino/1563878)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript show milliseconds as days:hours:mins without seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528382/javascript-show-milliseconds-as-dayshoursmins-without-seconds)

Answer (score 2):

Please check below snippet. After passing milliseconds you will find result in days hours and minutes.

```js
function dhm(t){
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
        d = Math.floor(t / cd),
        h = Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
        m = Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000),
        pad = function(n){ return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; };
  if( m === 60 ){
    h++;
    m = 0;
  }
  if( h === 24 ){
    d++;
    h = 0;
  }
  return d +" days : "+ pad(h) +" hours : "+ pad(m) + " mins ";
}
var days = (473 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var hours = (17 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var mins = (28 * 60 * 1000);
var milliseconds  = days + hours + mins;
console.log( dhm( milliseconds ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var milliseconds = 1000000000000;
var dateStr = new Date(milliseconds);
var humanreadableStr = dateStr.getDay() +'Days '+dateStr.getHours() +'Hours '+dateStr.getMinutes() +'Minutes '+dateStr.getSeconds() +'Seconds';
```