# How do you compare selector attributes in Testcafe?

Tags: testing, attributes, automated-tests, selector, testcafe

I'm trying to compare the date of videos on a webpage to today's date. If the difference between the two dates is more than X days, report back as false.

The videos on the webpage have a tag in them  which uses the format yyyy-mm-dd

I've got a selector set up to find the videos `const videoDate = Selector('OPTA-video').withAttribute('data-secondary-time')`

Now how do I set a variable to today's date and compare the two? I'm completely stuck!

I was using Katalon Studio before and here's the groovy script that did the same job:

```
String videoDate = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('OPTA-video'), 'data-secondary_time')

LocalDate todaysDate = LocalDate.now()

LocalDate videoDateParsed = LocalDate.parse(videoDate, dtf)

if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(videoDateParsed, todaysDate) > 1) {
    KeywordUtil.markFailed('The videos are 2+ days old.')
} else {
    KeywordUtil.logInfo('The videos are up to date.')
}
```

Comment: Can you find the element of date object ? (xpath/css)?

Comment: Yeah so the Xpath for the element is `//*[@id="opta-app"]/ul[1]/li/a/span[1]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`getAttribute`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes) TestCafe method to access an attribute value. Then, parse the attribute value into the JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```js
String videoDate = Selector('OPTA-video').getAttribute('data-secondary-time');

Date videoDateParsed = Date.parse(videoDate);

Date todaysDate = Date.now()

...
```

In the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528382/javascript-show-milliseconds-as-dayshoursmins-without-seconds) you can find how to compare Date objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the scripts that I am using.

```
//getting your XPath test value into a string
    String ann_time = 
       WebUI.getText(findTestObject("ObjectRepository/navigateTOElement/announcements_date"))

        //converting time to simple date format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm')

        Date sdf_anntime = sdf.parse(new String(ann_time))

        //getting Current time
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm')

        dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT'))

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm')

        currDate = dateFormatLocal.parse(dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()))

        // time gap in long format
        long duration = currDate.getTime() - sdf_anntime.getTime()

        //time gap to mins
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)


        //compare time gap with globale variable 
        if (diffInMinutes < GlobalVariable.News_updated_time) {


            log.logInfo("system is getting updated,last updated "+ diffInMinutes + "min ago")

        } else {

            CustomKeywords.'errorMessage.logFailed.markStepFailed'('from 1 h, system was not updated')

            log.logInfo('from '+ diffInMinutes+ 'h, system was not updated')
        }
```

Comment: Please note that  :- GlobalVariable.News_updated_time  is dynamic days gap (ex : 1,2)